# JNI GetObjectClass always returns java/lang/Class

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

env->CallVoidMethod is returning java/lang/Class when using

```
env->GetObjectClass(aobject); //aobject was the argument sent by JNI to C++
```

aobject is a Java object that implements an interface.

```
jobject obj = env->GetObjectClass(aobject)
```

is supposed to return the Java object but instead is returning java/lang/Class

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error and had to ask around at work before I got a real answer.

The problem is that when you designate your `native` method as `static`, it supplies an instance of the `jclass`, not a `jobject` instance of that class, as it's called from a static context. (If you call `getCanonicalName()` on that `jclass`, it will return your class's name.)

If the native method needs to be static, then you should pass in the instance as an argument if you need it. Otherwise, just make it not static and you should be all fixed.

Comment: This answer is good. However, you may be able to improve it with an example. Thank You for your contribution to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't regenerated your .h/.c file since you removed 'static' so your JNI method signature doesn't match the Java one. You have an extra jclass in the argument list that is only there for static methods. So you're going to get some very strange execution.

Comment: I just realized that I posted the version of my code when I was using the static method but my code has the correct signature (JNIEnv *,jobject,jobject,jobject). I got this API signature using javah

Comment: I found the problem but I can't answer my own question because I don't have enough reputation points :P... I'll post my answer in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was described in "The Java Native Interface - Programmer's Guide and Specification" by Shen Liang.

**"You can use Call< Type >Method family of functions to invoke interface methods as well. You must derive the method ID from the interface type"**

Comment: This isn't an answer to the problem you posted.